# How to Scale a Circular Background While Keeping an Image Fixed on Scroll in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm working on a React project where I want to create an effect where a circular background element scales up as the user scrolls down the page. However, I also want to keep an image inside this circular background fixed in size. Essentially, the circle grows larger, but the image remains the same size.

Here's my current code for this component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import PersonImg from "../assets/person.png";
import Image from "next/image";

const CircleScroll = () => {
  const [scaleFactor, setScaleFactor] = useState(1);

  // Update the scale factor based on the scroll position
  const handleScroll = () => {
    const scrollY = window.scrollY;

    const newScaleFactor = 1 + (scrollY / window.innerHeight) * 30;

    if (newScaleFactor <= window.innerWidth / 70) {
      setScaleFactor(newScaleFactor);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      className="grow-element flex justify-center items-center relative"
      style={{ transform: `scale(${scaleFactor})` }}
    >
      <Image
        className="w-[100px] h-[100px] fixed top-0"
        src={PersonImg}
        alt="person-image"
        width={"100"}
        height={"100"}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CircleScroll;
```

and the CSS

```
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #FFE67B;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: transform 0s ease-in-out;
  z-index: -10;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

When I scroll the page, the background element gets bigger but along with that the image too. I want the image to be fixed at the top of the element without increasing it's size. Any help on this would be appreciated. I've also attached the image if it looks confusing.
[image]

[image]

Comment: `clip-path` maybe can reach your goals, here is some example [animating-with-clip-path](https://css-tricks.com/animating-with-clip-path/), [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

Comment: Still the image gets bigger after clipping.

Comment: Here is my idea, make background full screen and set `clip-path: circle(10%)` and then when scroll make percent bigger so that the circle will be bigger. Last, REMOVE SCALE!

Comment: @init-qy the image is getting bigger inside the clip. You can try it out with you system itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transform` will affect element and its children, thats why the image will be bigger.

The first way is to take `image` out of `div`:

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
  let r = $(window).scrollTop() / window.innerHeight;
  //console.log(r)
  $(".main").css("transform", `scale(${r})`);
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main,.main-img {
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left:50%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: yellow;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.text {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h2 {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  
</div>
<img class="main-img" src="https://gravatar.com/avatar/ca219a282cd65353e6372369d7568863?s=400&d=robohash&r=x" width="100" style="margin-top: calc(100vh - 100px)">
<!-- <div class="cover"></div> -->
<div class="text">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The other way, as I comment, use `clip-path` to get similar results.

Here is the demo with simple html and css:

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
  let y = 100 + $(window).scrollTop() + "px";
  $(".main").css("clip-path", `circle(${y} at 50% 80%)`);
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  clip-path: circle(100px at 50% 80%);
}
.text {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h2 {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <img src="https://gravatar.com/avatar/ca219a282cd65353e6372369d7568863?s=400&d=robohash&r=x" width="100" style="margin-top: calc(100vh - 100px)">
</div>
<!-- <div class="cover"></div> -->
<div class="text">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```